# clickable text from jTextPane

Tags: jtextpane, clickable

I am implementing a function which sets text to `jTextPane`. So when user clicks certain word in `jTextPane`, the definition of that word should be displayed in `jTextArea`. I know how to display text in `jTextPane` and in `jTextArea`. What's troubling me is that when I click in `jTextPane` **the whole text is getting selected instead of selecting that particular word** :'( . I have done some research on caret positions and all but I can't quite get it. This is as far as I got:

```
private void jTextPane1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
        try
        {
           StyledDocument doc=(StyledDocument) jTextPane1.getDocument();;
            Element ele = doc.getCharacterElement(jTextPane1.viewToModel(evt.getPoint()));
            AttributeSet as = ele.getAttributes();
           /* Here after getting the word from jTextPane we print the definition 
             of that word in jTextArea... I got the code for this part */ 

        }
}
```

How can I get only the clicked word??[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `viewToModel()` method (in fact you already use it) to detect charatcer position for the clicked point.

Then use `javax.swing.text.Utilities` class. It has methods:

```
public static final int getWordStart(JTextComponent c, int offs)
public static final int getWordEnd(JTextComponent c, int offs)
```

Just pass the position obtained from `viewToModel()` call and get start and end positions for the clicked word. Then you can select it by setSelectionStart()/setSelectionEnd() calls passing the word start/end offsets.

Comment: It worked!! Million thanks to you @StanislavL I was working on this particular part from days..

Answer (score 2):

People who got the same problem... Here's how I solved it.
First, add `mouseClicked` event to your `jTextPane` (this can be done in design tab in netbeans). Write the code to get the clicked text from the `jTextPane`. Here's the code:

```
   private void jTextPane1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
   try
    {
            String wrd=null;
            int pt=jTextPane1.viewToModel(evt.getPoint());
            int spt=Utilities.getWordStart(jTextPane1,pt);
            int ept=Utilities.getWordEnd(jTextPane1,pt);
            jTextPane1.setSelectionStart(spt);
            jTextPane1.setSelectionEnd(ept);
            wrd=jTextPane1.getSelectedText();
            System.out.println("TextPane word="+wrd);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//You can get text without highlighting it like:

private void jTextPaneMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
try
    {

            String word = null;
            int point = jTextPane.viewToModel(evt.getPoint());
            int startPoint = Utilities.getWordStart(jTextPane,point);
            int endPoint = Utilities.getWordEnd(jTextPane,point);

            word = jTextPane.getText(startPoint, endPoint-startPoint);
            System.out.println("Clicked word"+word);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```